# Send an audio FILE and JSON string in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json, file-upload

I'm trying to send both an audio file and a JSON string to a PHP server. With the following code will send the JSON, but the file arrives empty. If I put the JSON block below the audio block, the file with completely arrive, but the JSON is empty. Any thoughts?

```
- (void)sendFile:(NSString *)filePath URL:(NSString *)urlString JSON:(NSData *)jsonBody
    {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"UserToken"]) {
            // add the header to the request.
            [request addValue:[defaults objectForKey:@"UserToken"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];
        }

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"body\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"recording\"; filename=\"recording.wav\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // set request body
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // send the request (submit the form) and get the response
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how you're writing the file to disk on the server? And what backend are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The code above is correct.

The PHP code was looking for the file variable `file` when it should be looking for `recording`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the file easily as a string parameter by converting the binary to Base64 string.

Take a look at [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) for information on Base64 encoding on Mac and iOS.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Just note the string will be approx 30% larger than the binary.