# How to convert audio binary on server from iPhone POST request?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I have a working POST request that will send a CAF audio file (recorded on the iPhone with AVAudioRecorder) to a web server -- the request itself is structured similarly to [Send an audio FILE and JSON string in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549219/send-an-audio-file-and-json-string-in-ios).

The server correctly receives the file, but I'm having trouble converting it into a format that will play directly in a browser. In addition to every audio/iPhone/server post I could find on stack overflow, I've looked into ffmpeg and HTML5 audio as well, but couldn't find clear instructions on how to convert the received audio binary to a browser-playable format. Essentially, I need to understand how to accomplish Arun's server-side suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750329/how-to-send-audio-file-through-http-post-to-a-server-from-ios).

I know that Audacity, Soundbooth, etc. will allow you to use the raw data and save it as another format, but I need this to be done programmatically on the server. If there are any suggestions they would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: How are you posting the audio file to the server and is the file playable once it reaches the server?

Comment: Actually figured it out with a really simple solution -- change "sound.caf" to "sound.wav" in the AVAudioRecorder filename. Can't believe it was that simple...!

Comment: Wasn't aware you could record in .wav file, well good to see you solved it.